# Text Wrapping when Printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, word-wrap

I'm trying to make sure that the words and characters on my `PrintDocument` go all the way to the page margins and wrap. At the moment it wraps with quite a gap:

The red is the margin. I want the text to go all the way to the margin, if it exceeds, then wrap it.

[image]

This is my `PrintDocument` code:

```
Private Sub PrintDoc_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage

    Dim PrintFont As New Font(TheTextBox.FontFamily.ToString(), Convert.ToSingle(TheTextBox.FontSize))
    Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = TheTextBox.Text.Length
    Dim linesPerPage As Integer = TheTextBox.LineCount

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.MarginBounds)
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(StringToPrint, PrintFont, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericDefault, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(StringToPrint, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)

    StringToPrint = StringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)
    e.HasMorePages = StringToPrint.Length > 0

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `justify` mode in your text like in Word.

Comment: Any idea where to start? Msdn code project?

Comment: Searching for `justify text algorithm` might be a good start !